# Can anybody explain this JS code inside the audio tag?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I'm creating a React app. While looking at this example: https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/pen/XpKrrW?editors=0010 I found a peculiar way to manage the audio tag at lines 211 - 213. Can anybody explain to me what the author is doing here?

I looked at the documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp but ref isn't even in the default properties.

```
<audio id="beep" preload="auto" 
    src="<<audio url>>"
    ref={(audio) => { this.audioBeep = audio; }} />
```

Comment: the `ref` callback is basically assigning the "true" audio element (behind the JSX tag), to the class member field "audioBeep"

Comment: Is it equivalent to assigning it using document.getElementById('beep') ?

Comment: Pretty much, expect you'll want to use refs rather than to interact with the DOM via `document.getElementById()` to ensure that you're "referencing" a DOM element that persistently exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `react` property, check this out [ref functions](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/refs/)